# How can I upload images from pc to mobile app (automated)

Tags: python, emulator

I wrote a Selenium script that downloads images from multiple sites, which I would like the bot to automatically upload them to **ifunny** app.

This is an app for posting funny memes and images they do have a website [ifunny.co](https://ifunny.co/) but unfortunately the website doesn't allow to upload even with mobile phone headers (Selenium) so I am stuck with the app. Is there a Python way (module library) that allows connecting script to *Nox*, *bluestacks* emulators to directly upload?

If there is another way of doing so, please advice.